# why GPU have so many core/compute unit

Tags: opencl, gpu

I know commonly CPU has many compute units or CUDA cores. This make it suitable for compute-intensive algorithms.

But why it has so much more cores than CPU? When rending image, which kinds of algorithms are parallelizable?

Answer (score 2):

This huge number of compute units is necessary for fast processing of frames when applying **shaders**.

This type of computing is highly parallelizable as each shader will be applied n times (maybe one time by pixel) and often in an independent way on the same frame.

Note that each **compute-unit** is made of many **shader-cores**.

This is why shaders support is a prerequisite for OpenCL as it implies some dedicated cores to do the rendering job, cores that can be "hijacked" to do other things => this is called **GPGPU**.